# How to implement different events through single tap and double tap in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using LibGdx to develop an android game . I have implemented the gesture listener class in my InputHandler class . Now in the tap method I have to implement two features , short jump and long jump on single tap and double tap respectively. When I try to implement it using the count value of the function , the problem is when I double tap the screen the count value firstly becomes 1 and then 2 so it does not go into the second if statement and and the feature of short jump occurs. So how to differentiate single jump from double jump? Below is the code

```
@Override
public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(count==1)
    {
        //feature 1
    }
    if(count==2)
    {
        //feature 2

    }


    return true;
    }
```

Comment: so you want us to write the whole logic?? better eill be u give ur ;ogic and we can fix the bug. it will be a faster approach

Comment: We have the logic implemented, just that its is not entering into the second if statement.So can you help us with that?

Comment: Maybe your doubletap is too slow to detect.  Try to increase your delay with `GestureDetector.setTapCountInterval(float tapCountInterval) `

Comment: So, you think that it enters block #1 both cases? What is the value of the `count` for the second tap?

Comment: Yes it enters bolck #1 in both cases. but when I only give condition for count =2 , then it works but when i provide both count =1 and count =2 the latter doesnt work .

Comment: how are you reseting your counter. print the counter value on every tap to see if counter value is proper or not

Comment: On printing the counter value , when i tap the screen it shows 1 and when i double tap it shows 1 and then 2(one after the other)

Comment: what exactly is happening is that when you double tap the counter will immediately enter first if block so second block will never get executed. firstly use else if not just if secondly u need to implement some kind of delay mechanism so that u can check tow fast the tapping is then decide. simply counter wont solve this one

Answer (score 4):

two solutions comes to my mind:

1. **Use delay technique** which would come with following steps:

   - when tap-count is 2 : trigger action for double tap
   - when tap-count is 1 : wait some time, if not tapped second time trigger action for single tap

code would be something like:

```
if(count==1)
{
    if(wait) //wait is a boolean tells if it was tapped once already
    {
        if(getCurrentTime() - startTime > interval) //getCurrentTime() return current time or frame count or something
        {
            wait = false;
            //feature 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wait = true;
        startTime = getCurrentTime(); //start time keeps the time when tapped first one
    }
}
if(count==2)
{
    //feature 2

}


return true;
}
```

the problem I see here is firstly  "how to choose long enough interval for waiting for secon tap?" - if you will choose to short it will be impossible to make double tap, if too long there will be a lag and user will see that the character is not jumping directly after tap

2. **Divide jump for a pieces and trigger them depends on tap count**

And it depends on your "jumping" mechanism. If it be something like:

**A**. add force to jump

**B**. keep adding some force for some **time** to keep object in the air

**C**. avoid adding force to take object down back to ground

you could modify **time** to keep object in the air longer. If your "jumping mechanism" is more like impuls adding force (in upper example it would be variant without B point) you could add the force in A again for a some time and if user tapped second time before this interval ends keep on adding it just longer.

This solution eliminates lag problem but depends on "jumping mechanism" you choose.

Regards,
Michał

Comment: solution 1 is a better approach

Comment: Yeah , i also thought about this logic , just not able to calculate time between two consecutive taps. Can you help with that?

Comment: You just have to have some external variable for keep **startime** (it can be in your class outside the listener) and for example use **TimeUtils.millis()** as getCurrentTime() from my example. The **interval** you should set yourself - as long as goo in your opinion

Comment: current time can be obtained through "system.currentTimeMills or "TimeUtils.millis" and the "delay interval" can be set manually but what is the logic by which we can check that screen is tapped again within the delay time interval